# Probability of Reaching D before E

Tags: markov-chains, random-walk

> Consider a simple finite graph  such as this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0RJJ.png
>
> If we start at $A$, what is the probability of hitting $D$ before $E$?

I know that the probability of hitting $D$ before $E$ is the same as the probability of hitting $E$ before $D$ , due to symmetry.

I calculated the transition matrix to be :

$$
P=  \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 1 &1 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
with states A,B,C,D,E

and the adjency matrix:
$$
B=  \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1/3 & 1/3 &1/3 & 0 \\
    1/3 & 0 & 1/3 & 0 & 1/3 \\
    1/2 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    1/2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
    0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
with states A,B,C,D,E

What should i do next?

Comment: "I know that the probability of hitting $D$ before $E$ is the same as the probability of hitting $E$ before $D$..." If you would be correct in this then the probability of hitting $D$ before $E$ would equal $\frac12$ which is not the case. There is only symmetry if we start in $C$.

Answer (score 1):

For $L\in\{A,B,C\}$ let $p_L$ denote the probability of hitting $D$ before $E$ if we start in $L$.

To be found is $p_A$ and we have the following equalities:

- $p_A=\frac13+\frac13p_B+\frac13p_C$
- $p_B=\frac13p_A+\frac13p_C$
- $p_C=\frac12p_A+\frac12p_B$

The equalities enable us to find $p_A=\frac58$, $p_B=\frac38$ and $p_C=\frac12$.

---

More shortly it is evident that $p_C=\frac12$ and that $p_B=1-p_A$ on base of symmetry.

Then the equality under the first bullet becomes:

- $p_A=\frac13+\frac13(1-p_A)+\frac13\frac12$

And it immediately follows that $p_A=\frac58$.

Comment: How are these equalities found?

Comment: Starting in $A$ there is probability $\frac13$ that we go to $D$ in which case it is for certain that $D$ will be hit before $E$. Further there is probability $\frac13$ that we arrive in $B$ in which case there is probability $p_B$ on hitting $D$ before $E$, and there is probability $\frac13$ that we arrive in $C$ in which case there is probability $p_C$ on hitting $D$ before $E$. So $p_A=\frac13\times1+\frac13\times p_B+\frac13\times p_C$. The other equalities are found similarly.